# Integral of $f(x,\lambda)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x-\lambda x^2}}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

How can I compute the indefinite integral:

\begin{equation}
I=\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{x-\lambda x^2}}dx
\end{equation}
with $\lambda$ a positive real parameter?
Thank you!

Comment: Note that you can take the factor $\lambda$ out of the integral with the change of variable $y=\lambda x$.

Answer (score 1):

By completing the square, $x-\lambda x^2=1/(4\lambda^2)-(x-\lambda/2)^2$, then use a trigonometric substitution.